# Is there a way to generate description of libraries in Python requirement.txt

Tags: python, pypi

I am trying to understand an existing big python project which has lot of dependencies listed in requirement.txt. I like to understand what each libraries is meant for.

If there is a way to generate a short description given by them from pypi.org or other sources, that would greatly help.

For example:

```
#requirement.txt
gluonts
aiohttp
```

Expected outcome:

```
gluonts | GluonTS is a Python toolkit for probabilistic time series modeling
aiohttp | Async http client/server framework
```

Is there a tool (command line / online) that can provide descriptive insights on python dependencies ?

Comment: there's the `help` function, for example `import numpy; help(numpy)`. if you need this as a `str`, you can also use `numpy.__doc__` (this works for every librry with a docstring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get a description of packages installed using pip.

```
pip show [options] <package>
```

For example

```
pip show requests
Name: requests
Version: 2.25.1
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: https://requests.readthedocs.io
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: ..\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages
Requires: urllib3, certifi, chardet, idna
Required-by:
```

You can use the summary field as a description. This of course relies upon the author having provided a sufficiently clear description.

You can do this inside a python script using the following

```
from pip._internal import main as pipmain
description = pipmain(['show','requests'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have those packages installed you can use `pip show <package-name>`. For example:

```sh
$ pip show aiohttp
Name: aiohttp
Version: 3.7.3
Summary: Async http client/server framework (asyncio)
Home-page: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp
Author: Nikolay Kim
Author-email: fafhrd91@gmail.com
License: Apache 2
Location: /home/jack/repo/global-search-ingestion/global_search_lib/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: typing-extensions, yarl, async-timeout, chardet, attrs, multidict
Required-by: faust, aiohttp-cors
```

To run this over your `requirements.txt`, you can use `cut` and `xargs`

```sh
pip show $(cat requirements.txt | cut -d "=" -f 1 | xargs)
```

And this will list out metadata for each library in you `requirements.txt`.